# What exactly is 'osobaya sayanskaya' in House of Cards S03E03?

Tags: vodka

In the S03E03 of House of Cards, the Russian president brings this vodka for the US president. Is this real or just a made up vodka since I couldn't find any results on google.
Cheers!

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to find a freely available image or video clip of it? I'm guessing the current answer might be based on similar appearances, but I haven't seen the show.

Comment: No image, @Jolenealaska uploaded one in her answer though.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, it appears to be totally fictional.

[image: 1]

It's referred to as $750,000, with a bottle of gold.

That could be real, except that it doesn't appear to be.

You can spend that much on a bottle of Russian vodka, but none of the bottles look like that.

[10 Most expensive vodkas](http://www.complex.com/pop-culture/2012/11/most-expensive-vodkas/)

Comment: Wow.. I wasn't expecting to get any answers, I am overwhelmed with the responses. 
Yes, he mentions it is worth $750,000. That link, nice find! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*Osobaya Sayanskaya* literally translates to *Sayanskaya Deluxe* or *Special Sayanskaya*, possibly implying that its origins are in the [Sayan Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayan_Mountains) region. There is no real brand of vodka like that, although [*Sayanskaya Kristaljnaya* (*Crystal Sayanskaya*) vodka does seem to exist](http://stopalko.info/?q=/yetiketki_alkogoljnyh_napitkov/vodka/vodka_sayanskaya_kristaljnaya). It’s not at all famous or of known special quality however.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not real, but it was probably based on russobaltique vodka.

[image: http://dartzkombat.com/f/galleries/l/77198.JPG]